# Eth smart contract brownie abi too long?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, brownie

I use brownie to deploy my contracts and I'm very satsfied with it. My question is that I recentely got into web development and I'm trying to connect my front end with the contract. I know I need the contracts abi for that but when I deploy the contract with brownie and then copy the abi it is 10 000 lines of code compared to let's say hard hat where it is only around 150.

Can I use the brownie abi for the front end or do I need to use abi from either remix or hardhat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile with brownie, compiled code is placed into `build` directory as a .json file. That 10.000 lines of code is not abi, abi is the first property of that json file.

ABI is standard so abi generated from remix or hardhad should also work.